# Understanding Quotient Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am watching a video on [Field Extensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gcb9fBX4Vw) (trying to self "relearn" some Abstract Algebra before I take it again).  I struggled with it as an undergrad, so I'm trying to get a leg up.

The example is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle{x^2+1}\rangle$.  I'm trying to deduce in my mind what elements of this division ring "look" like.

From other places on this site, the internet, etc, I get the following picture.

First, $\langle{x^2+1}\rangle$ is a group generated by $x^2+1$, so basically all polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of the form $(x^2+1)p(x), p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Second, since we are talking quotients here, I'm looking then at 
$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle{x^2+1}\rangle=\{q(x)+\langle{x^2+1}\rangle|q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]\}$$

So, would elements of $x+\langle{x^2+1}\rangle$ look like below?
$$x+(x^2+1)=x^2+x+1$$
$$x+(x^2+1)^2=x^2+3x+1$$
$$x+(x^2+1)x^4=x^6+2x^5+x^4+x$$

If I am completely wrong, can some one please elaborate on why my thinking is flawed?

Comment: Yep, that's what it would be.  $x+p(x)(x^2+1)$ more generally.  As far as intuition of what working in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is like, however, I find it better to think of it as "working in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but where $x^2+1=0$"  This viewpoint is nice, particularly in this example, as saying $x^2+1=0$ is basically saying that we've adjoined a square-root of $-1$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ (and so $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)$).

Comment: That is wonderful.  So, while I was sitting here staring, I had a thought.  Naturally I always thought of "fractions" when considering Quotient spaces, rings, etc.  But basically, you can get this from the division algorithm for polynomials since polynomials can be written of the form $$f(x)=g(x)p(x)+r(x)$$ and I could say that $f(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle{g(x)}\rangle$?

Comment: If the video you are watching has Val Kilmer in it, try to find some other way to study quotient rings.

Comment: @Iceman yes, assuming that $\deg r(x)<\deg g(x)$ or $r(x)=0$.  This is what Tobias points out, i.e. that there will be a unique polynomial of degree at most $1$ in the coset $p(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$ for each $p(x)$.  The same idea can be extended when you replace $x^2+1$ by another polynomial $g(x)$, but then the "at most $1$" will be "less than $\deg g(x)$"

Comment: @WillJagy, i mean, he is the Iceman....

Comment: I mean, that is me....

Comment: Sure; meanwhile, how would you express the product $\left( ax+b + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \right) \left( cx+d + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \right) $ in the form $ \left( ex+f + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \right)?$

Comment: okay, so it would be $(acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd+\langle{x^2+1}\rangle$.  Then you can divide by $ac$ since we are in the field $\mathbb{Q}$, which gives $x^2+\frac{ad+bc}{ac}x+1-(1-\frac{bd}{ac})$.  Now you got your $x^2+1$ and you are left with your $ex+f$?

Comment: @WillJagy is this accurate?

Comment: well, no, good thing I brought it up. Thank you for giving it a try. You do not divide by $ac.$ You don't force the appearance of $x^2 + 1$ in some artificial way. All that happens is $x^2 + 1$ is regarded as $0;$ meaning that, if it occurs, $x^2$ is regarded as $-1.$ The correct representative for the product is $e = ad+bc,$ then $f = bd-ac,$ together $$  (ad+bc) x + (bd-ac) + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle $$

Comment: If you know complex numbers, this is ***exactly*** the same calculation as $(ai+b)(ci+d),$ which comes out to $(ad+bc)i + (bd - ac)$

Comment: Now i see it.  This would make sense, since we are dealing with $i$ anyway since our quotient ring's polynomial ideal has $i$ as a root?

Comment: I can see more now why it is also referred to as "mod $x^2+1$

Comment: You can do the same thing with matrices. Since I was using $b$ for the constant part, the product would be $$  \left( \begin{array}{rr} b & a \\ -a & b \end{array}  \right)  \left( \begin{array}{rr} d & c \\ -c & d \end{array}  \right).  $$ With some care, the same thing can be done, using 3 by 3 matrices, for $\mathbb Q[x]/ \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle;$ indeed, for any irreducible monic cubic. More work, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be focusing on understanding the elements of a single coset. But really, that is not so important. The important thing to understand the quotient is to understand the cosets all together.

A good way to do this is to realize (in this case) that each coset has a unique element of degree at most $1$. Now you can play around with multiplying and adding these representatives, by remembering to subtract multiples of $x^2 + 1$ to keep the degree at most $1$.

Comment: Okay, then all the cosets (the quotient) would be $ax+b+\langle{x^2+1}\rangle$

Comment: @Iceman Yes, precisely (and as noted in the comments, the multiplication will make $x$ behave like $i$).

Answer (score 2):

A variant on this way of seeing things is that when you do operations on representative of cosets, each time you meet some $x^2+1$, you can replace it by $0$ ($x^2+1$ is ‘killed’ in the quotient. In other words, each time you have an $x^2$, you replace it with $-1$, an $x^3$ is replaced with $-1$, $x^4$ with $1$, &c.